# How to generate random numeric slugs for a custom post type?

Tags: permalinks, slug

I have this PHP code to generate a random numeric string:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 12)
{
    global $generatedStrings;
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    if (isset($generatedStrings[$randomString])) {
        $randomString = generateRandomString($length);
    }
    $generatedStrings[$randomString] = $randomString;
    return $randomString;
}

$generatedStrings = array();

foreach(range(1, 100000) as $num) {
    echo "\n".$num."\t : ".generateRandomString();
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help figure out how to integrate this code with WordPress to auto-generate strings as slugs for a custom post type.

Any guidance you can provide is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
function wpse_18293_get_random_string ($number_of_chars_to_use)  {

    $upper_case_charachters = range('A', 'Z');

    while($cnt < $number_of_chars_to_use) {
        $random_string.= $upper_case_charachters[mt_rand(0,    count($upper_case_charachters)-1)];
        $cnt++;
    } 
    return $random_string
}

$random_string = wpse_18293_get_random_string('10');
```

The '10' can be any number, and the function will pass back a string of random charachters that many charachters long. Note, the function name can be anything you want, I named is as such to avoid function name conflicts.

what this does, is iterate $number_of_chars_to_use number of times, each loop it picks a random charachter from $uppser_case_charachters and adds it to a string. Voila, instant random charachter string.

It's worth noting, the $upper_case_charachters is just an array filled with the alphabet. If you wanted numbers, you could easily swap range('0', '9');

Comment: Thank you, @hybrid-web-dev! Much appreciated! Would try it right way, but I'm not sure if this code is a function that should be included in functions.php?! If so, how do I assign this code to work on one custom post type only? Kind regards, rey

Comment: I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Hi @hybrid-web-dev. I get a blank page when I put this code in functions.php :(

Comment: Forgot to add a ; at the end of the $random_string = wpse_18293_get_random_string('10');

Comment: Added a ; at the end of return $random_string, too. Not getting a blank page anymore :). But how do I add this to one custom post type only instead of globally? For example, the 'image' post type. So I'd generate urls like mysite.com/image/948593839215

Comment: Easy, just hook into the post save / creation process, do a conditional check for post type, and if it matches, then simply proceed with the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how you can auto generate numeric slugs, other than the post IDs:

```
/**
 * Auto generate numeric slugs for a given custom post type (via post.php screen)
 * Requires PHP 5.3+
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169907/26350
 */
add_action( 'load-post.php', function(){
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ) {
        if(
            'post' === $data['post_type']   // <-- Edit the cpt to your needs!
            && empty( $data['post_name'] )
            && isset( $postarr['post_ID'] )
            && $postarr['post_ID'] * 1 > 0
        )
        {
            //----------------------------------
            // Method with post ID reference (not random):
            //
            $data['post_name'] = sprintf( '%u', crc32( $postarr['post_ID'] ) );

            //----------------------------------
            // Method without post ID reference (random):
            //                 
            // $data['post_name'] = rand( 10000000, 99999999 );        
        }
        return $data;
    }, 10, 2 );
});
```

where you can modify the post type to your needs.

This will kick in on the `post.php` screen and not the `post-new.php` screen.

You can easily test the collisions of the `crc32()` PHP function, for post ID from 1 to 100.000, using the script in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744968/2078474). I tested it up to one million without any collisions.

Notice that if the unlikely thing will happen, that you generate a previous existing slug, then WordPress will take care of it as usual via the `wp_unique_post_slug()` function.

Hopefully you can adjust this further to your needs.

Comment: Hi @birgire! Unfortunately the code didn't work :( I suppose to replace only 'post_type', correct? And put it in the theme's functions.php, correct?

Comment: Hi @rey, yes just change the `'post'` value to your needs. This should work from `functions.php`. Must the slugs be *numeric* only or can it be *alpha-numeric*?

Comment: Numeric only ;) To generate urls like, for example: designspiration.net/image/411126849521/

Comment: Ah, I was replacing the wrong thing! Sorry, my bad, it works now!! Many thanks @birgire! :) If I want a longer length, I just need to add zero's and nine's, correct?

Comment: ok great, yes you could increase the 0's and 9's. I updated the answer with a restriction to the `post.php` screen and I added a `crc32()` example.

Comment: Hi @birgire, this new code doesn't work :( Any chance I can get the previous one?

Comment: It worked for new posts on my install. Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? You can always access the revisions on this site for all answers. Here are [my revisions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/169907/revisions).

Comment: Hi @birgire - I get a blank page...

Comment: Blank page could be a PHP syntax error in your pasted code. Please check out the update (for some unknown reason the return was missing when I copied the code from my install, sorry about that). You could also try to switch methods.

Comment: working now :) But what the method with post ID reference do? It seems to be generating random numbers too.. per example: 4194326291

Comment: you get always the same output, for a given post ID, using the first method. Another fixed output method would be the use for example the post date in the unix time format.

Comment: ah ok! @birgire, once again thank you very much for all your help! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Yet another fixed output method, based on the post ID, would be to use the decimals of the `1/post_ID` fraction, or some other *injective* function of the post ID.

Comment: I wish I could understand what you're saying lol. I'm pretty much a php newbie. :)